# Refactoring after changing local variable into instance variable

Tags: objective-c

Am having some trouble with my code after changing a local variable into an instance variable. To be specific, I have been having trouble with my code in my HypnosisterAppDelegate.m file after changing one line of code from:

```
HypnosisView *view = [[HypnosisView alloc]initWithFrame:screenRect];
```

to

```
view = [[HypnosisView alloc]initWithFrame:screenRect];
```

I have commented out the error messages in HypnosisterAppDelegate.m Can you tell me what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

HypnosisterAppDelegate.m

```
#import "HypnosisterAppDelegate.h"
#import "HypnosisView.h"

@implementation HypnosisterAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

  CGRect screenRect = [[self window]bounds];

  // Create the UIScrollView to have the size of a window, matching its size
  view = [[HypnosisView alloc]initWithFrame:screenRect];
  [scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:1.0];  // Unknown receiver "scrollView"; should it be "UIScrollView"?
  [scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:5.0];  // Unknown receiver "scrollView"; should it be "UIScrollView"?

   //You will get a warning here, ignore it for now
 [scrollView setDelegate:self]; // Unknown receiver "scrollView"; should it be "UIScrollView"?

  [[self window] addSubview:scrollView]; // Unknown receiver "scrollView"; should it be "UIScrollView"?

  //Create the HypnosisView with a frame that is twice the size of the screen
  CGRect bigRect = screenRect;


  HypnosisView *view = [[HypnosisView alloc]initWithFrame:screenRect];

  // Add the HypnosisView as a subview of the scrollView instead of the window
  [scrollView addSubview:view]; // Unknown receiver "scrollView"; should it be "UIScrollView"?



  // Tell the scrollView how big its virtual world is
  [scrollView
   setContentSize:bigRect.size]; // Unknown receiver "scrollView"; should it be "UIScrollView"?

  BOOL success = [view becomeFirstResponder];
  if (success) {
    NSLog(@"HypnosisView became the first responder");
    } else {
    NSLog(@"Could not become the first responder");
  }

  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  return view;
}

@end
```

HypnosisView.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HypnosisView : UIView {

}

@property(nonatomic,strong)UIColor *circleColor;
@end
```

Comment: Where are you creating `scrollView`?

Comment: Think that was the problem: must have accidentally deleted a line: UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:screenRect]; It worked when I added it back in.Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Do you want to put your comment in the answer area so that I can give you positive feedback?

Comment: If you like. My comment was intended rhetorically, but I'm glad it was helpful. (You can answer your own questions when you solve them yourself, if you want, although you have to wait a few hours to post.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a variable called `scrollView` anywhere. I'd guess (especially from the comment `// Create the UIScrollView to have the size of a window, matching its size`, and also having gone through this book myself) that you meant to create a `UIScrollView`:

```
// not:  view = [[HypnosisView alloc]initWithFrame:screenRect];
// but:
UIScrollView * scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
```

and then add your `HypnosisView` later as a subview.